# How to check in the controller if a database contains an entry that has duplicate values before adding a new entry?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, controller

In the create method for my controller, I need to do a check before actually adding the object to the database. All I need to do is check if there is already an entry that has duplicate values for two of the attributes.

My current idea is to do a sql query to select all entries where those 2 values match the 2 of the current object, and if the count of this query is => 1, then just not adding the object to the database.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,name,winner,points,postDate")] Pick pick)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Picks WHERE [score] = @score AND [winner] = @winner", con);

            if (ModelState.IsValid && cmd.value == 0) //I know this is wrong but something like this
            {
                db.Picks.Add(pick);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(pick);
        }
```

The main thing I need to know are:

1. Where I put "Picks" in the query, is that the DB name or table name?
2. In the query, is "[score]" the correct way to write the attribute from a db, and is "@score" the correct way to refer to the value of the attribute of the object you are currently working with?
3. What would be the method of getting the amount of entries that the query returned?

Comment: 1. table or for some rdbms can be database.table

Comment: This project is badly designed, and open to problems such as sql injection. Use dependency injection to introduce service and data layers

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some things wrong here. First, you need to call ExecuteScalar() from your cmd object in order to get the count back. Second, you're not parameterizing your query. Third, don't get your count until you're sure your model is valid. Lastly, not major but I would add aliases to your query:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,name,winner,points,postDate")] Pick pick)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Picks p WHERE p.score = @score AND p.winner = @winner", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", points);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winner", winner);
            var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count == 0)
            {

                db.Picks.Add(pick);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
        }

        return View(pick);
    }
```

Not tested but should be close enough to get you going!

Answer (score 0):

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,name,winner,points,postDate")] Pick pick)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Picks WHERE [score] = 
        @score AND [winner] = @winner", con);
        SqlDataAdpater _dt=new SqlDataAdpater(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", pick.points);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winner", pick.winner);
        DataTable  _dt=new DataTable();
       _dt.fill(_dt);
       if(_dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {

            db.Picks.Add(pick);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }

    return View(pick);
}
```

Class property can not be accessed directly you need to use ClassName.propertyName